# Re-positioning column in database removes auto increment constraint

Tags: mysql

This is somewhat strange, but noticed this many times while working. I have a table in which there is column name 'id' with auto_increment constraint. If i try to re-position this column (i.e. id) auto_increment constraint get removed. Below i provided images and query. This operation is performed on mysql database.

Original table,
[image]

Query : `alter table login_client modify id int(11) first;`

After query,
[image]

As you can see in second image. constraint auto_incremnt just disappered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `auto_increment` is extra attribute of column like `Default Value`.

When you [modify column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) in any table you have to give all extra attributes of column.

```
alter table login_client modify id int(11) auto_increment first;
```

Comment: Do you  know what is the reason of doing this? What impact will happen if mysql does not remove auto_increment attribute.

Comment: ALTER TABLE makes a temporary copy of the original table. When you use CHANGE or MODIFY, column_definition must include the data type and all attributes that should apply to the new column, other than index attributes such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE. Attributes present in the original definition but not specified for the new definition are not carried forward.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

It says:

> When you use CHANGE or MODIFY, column_definition must include the data type and all attributes that should apply to the new column, other than index attributes such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE.

This is by design, therefore when you alter the column in this way you are required to re-create any attributes that you want to apply to it. Note that AUTO_INCREMENT is technically an attribute, not a constraint.

You can re-specify the auto_increment attribute quite easily in your command, like this:

```
alter table login_client modify id int(11) auto_increment first;
```

Comment: I was not aware of this fact. Do you  know what is the reason of doing this?

Comment: No, I'm not a MySQL developer. Maybe there's a technical reason in the background - perhaps in reality the column is dropped and re-created, or something. All I know is that you are required to re-specify the attribute. Since you already know what the attribute is from your current table definition, it isn't hard to add it in to your command. I've edited the answer to give an example.

Comment: @JoneDotosvky If omitting the AUTO_INCREMENT still kept it active on the column... how *would* you remove it, without creating a new special statement?

Comment: @DCoder What  you want to say? Be simple.

Comment: @JoneDotosvky DCoder means that this design is necessary, because otherwise there is no way to deliberately remove an attribute from a column (if that should be required in a different situation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
It will make auto increment the given field.

```
alter table login_client modify id  int  auto_increment
```